# C# Web exception unexpected EOF

Tags: c#, security, ssl, web, webclient

I am attempting to download a json web page from imdb to find an actor.

```
        try
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string content = wc.DownloadString("https://v2.sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/names/b/brad.json");
            }
        }
        catch (WebException x)
        {
            x.ToString();
        }
```

Whenever I attempt to make the download.

The exception given is:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

And the inner web exception is:

```
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
```

From what I've read. This happens because one of imdb's servers is misconfigured.

To try and solve this, I used

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)(3072);
```

To set the security protocol to Tls12 which does solve the issue on my PC.

However, when I try to use it on my second PC. That line throws the exception:

```
System.NotSupported: The requested security protocol is not supported
```

Which I assume means that it doesn't have tls12 support on that PC.

I have the .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on that PC and I cannot install .NET Framework 4.7 because it fails in the installation.

I assume the security protocol comes with 4.7, but I don't see that confirmed on MSDN.

How can I get the web page to download on this second PC?

Is there a way for me to manually install the Tls12 protocol?

Is there an alternative using HttpWebRequest or some standalone executable instead?

Comment: Support ended for 4.5.1 a long time ago. Why are you still using it? Even if you can't do 4.7 there's still 4.5.2 and 4.6 that you can try.

Comment: @mason, the optimal solution would be something that works with .NET Framework 3.5 or even independent of the .NET Framework. If I have issue, then other people will as well so I rather not have such high and buggy dependencies.

Comment: By "such high and buggy dependencies" do you mean "running on a supported version like any sane person"? And what version of Windows is the one that's failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the cURL binary since it doesn't depend on the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend updating to the latest .Net Framework "4.7.X".

As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.7, the default value of this
>   property is SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault. This allows .NET
>   Framework networking APIs based on SslStream (such as FTP, HTTP, and
>   SMTP) to inherit the default security protocols from the operating
>   system or from any custom configurations performed by a system
>   administrator.

So theortically speaking, updating to the latest .Net Framework should fix the problem without changing any System Registry Values eg, Supporting lower TLS Version or overriding the Framework default behavior.

Also the reason why it only worked on your machine is probably, your machine supports TLS 1.2 which the other machine doesn't.

To check that you can check the registry on which Version are enabled:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
```

In case you need to enable TLS 1.2 (Which should be enabled by default if it's regulary updated) you can check the following articles:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi

https://www.itnota.com/enabling-tls-1-2-default-security-protocol-windows-servers/

To Sum it up:

- Try updating to the latest .Net Framework.
- if it wasn't possible
  then do use

  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
- if it didn't work on the other machine, then check the supported TLS 
  versions on the this machine

.